# Effect of double semicolon termination

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

We have a set of code where a line in SystemVerilog is terminated with a double semicolon vs. a single semicolon.  There is some debate as to the effect of having an extra semicolon in the HDL.

What does SystemVerilog do with an extra termination semicolon?  I presume it gets ignored by the interpreter, but maybe it's interpreter specific?

Answer (score 3):

The BNF has the term *statement_or_null* as well as a number of other places with _*or_null*

```
statement_or_null ::=
   statement
 | { attribute_instance } ;
```

So it is explicitly allowed by the BNF in a particular place. I can think of a few places where an extra semicolon would make a significant difference

```
fork
   #1 statement1;
   #4 statement2; ;
join_any
```

The null statement here means the join_any happens in 0 time instead of 1 time unit later.